# Angular 1.X binding html code with controller value doesn't show properly

Tags: angularjs, angular

I want to safely inject HTML with angular content into my site. However, even though the HTML binds the angular portion doesn't/ (swirly braces)

```
var app = angular.module('dashboardApp', ['ngSanitize']);

app.controller('Ctrl', ['$scope','$sce', function($scope, $sce) {

 $scope.hello = "world";
 $scope.NgBindHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml("<h1>{{hello}}</h1>");

}]);

HTML:

<div ng-bind-html="NgBindHtml"></div>
```

Gives:

[image]

Where it should say 'World'

Comment: I might be wrong, but I think you need `$compile` - `$sce.trustAsHtml($compile("<h1>{{hello}}</h1>")($scope));`

Comment: @tymeJV Nope doesn't seem to work

Comment: you maybe need to create a directive for that.

Answer (score 0):

If `NgBindHtml` is static html you need `$interpolate`:

```
 $scope.hello = "Hello";
 $scope.NgBindHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml($interpolate("<h1>{{hello}}</h1>")($scope));
```

If you want also to add bindings, than you need write directive to first $compile html and then add it to DOM.